# Ajax requests from front-end with jQuery Fancybox

Tags: wp-admin, ajax

I would like to be able to use the jQuery Fancybox's Ajax feature to request datas from the front-end.
Here is a part of the code i'm using on the plugin part :

```
wp_localize_script( 'wpPluginjs', 'ajax_vars', array(
           'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
           'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax-nonce' )
        )
);
```

And on the js part :

```
var url = ajax_vars.url;
var nonce = ajax_vars.nonce;

$( "#list" ).fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    title       : false,
    type: 'ajax',
    href: ajax_vars.url+'&nonce='+ajax_vars.nonce
});
```

But i actually keep having the following error when i click "#list" :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php&nonce=7bbd764db8"
```

I tried with a basic jQuery Ajax request and it worked like a charm.
It seems that there is a problem with Fancybox, it's still unable to find the correct "`admin-ajax.php`" url.

I also unsuccessfully tried to add `wp_localize_script()` to the `wp_enqueue_script(`) function that loads jQuery Fancybox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&nonce` should be `?nonce`. The `?` begins a query string, the `&` separates arguments within a query string.

Comment: Yep was a mistake, sorry, my mind was probably on another part of the code in that moment...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best practice but if i use the following href it works:

```
href: '../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?nonce='+ajax_var.nonce
```

Comment: Note the difference between what you've written into that URL and what you have above. In your non-working version: `&nonce`, in the version that works: `?nonce`.

Comment: You are right, i didn't even notice that part of the code...